# GUI freezes when drawing Wave from animation on JPanel though i used Swing Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, bufferedimage, paintcomponent

plese look at my code snippets , wha is wrong with it , it frrezes GUI when the Swing timer stats which is repeteadly paints on the jpnael ??

```
class WaveformPanel extends JPanel {

        Timer graphTimer = null;
        AudioInfo helper = null;

        WaveformPanel() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 80));
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            graphTimer = new Timer(15, new TimerDrawing());
        }

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 969991141812736791L;
        protected final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.white;
        protected final Color REFERENCE_LINE_COLOR = Color.black;
        protected final Color WAVEFORM_COLOR = Color.red;

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            int lineHeight = getHeight() / 2;
            g.setColor(REFERENCE_LINE_COLOR);
            g.drawLine(0, lineHeight, (int) getWidth(), lineHeight);

            if (helper == null) {
                return;
            }

            drawWaveform(g, helper.getAudio(0));

        }

        protected void drawWaveform(Graphics g, int[] samples) {

            if (samples == null) {
                return;
            }

            int oldX = 0;
            int oldY = (int) (getHeight() / 2);
            int xIndex = 0;

            int increment = helper.getIncrement(helper
                    .getXScaleFactor(getWidth()));
            g.setColor(WAVEFORM_COLOR);

            int t = 0;

            for (t = 0; t < increment; t += increment) {
                g.drawLine(oldX, oldY, xIndex, oldY);
                xIndex++;
                oldX = xIndex;
            }

            for (; t < samples.length; t += increment) {
                double scaleFactor = helper.getYScaleFactor(getHeight());
                double scaledSample = samples[t] * scaleFactor;
                int y = (int) ((getHeight() / 2) - (scaledSample));
                g.drawLine(oldX, oldY, xIndex, y);

                xIndex++;
                oldX = xIndex;
                oldY = y;
            }
        }

        public void setAnimation(boolean turnon) {
            if (turnon) {
                graphTimer.start();
            } else {
                graphTimer.stop();
            }
        }

        class TimerDrawing implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                byte[] bytes = captureThread.getTempBuffer();

                if (helper != null) {
                    helper.setBytes(bytes);
                } else {
                    helper = new AudioInfo(bytes);
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }

    }
```

I am calling setAnimation of WaveFormPanel from its parent class.when animation starts it does not draw anything but freezes. please , give me solution.

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `java.swingx.Timer` calls the `ActionPerformed` within the `EDT`.  The question then is, what's taking the time to render. It could be the call to `captureThread.getTempBuffer` it could be the construction of the help, but I suspect it's just the sheer amount of data you are trying to paint.

Having played with this recently, it takes quite a bit of time to process the waveform.

One suggestion might be to reduce the number of samples that you paint.  Rather then painting each one, maybe paint every second or forth sample point depending on the width of the component.  You should still get the same jist but without all the work...

**UPDATED**

All samples, 2.18 seconds

[image: AllSamples]

Every 4th sample, 0.711 seconds

[image]

Every 8th sample, 0.450 seconds

[image]

Rather then paint in response to the timer, maybe you need to paint in response to batches of data.

As your loader thread has a "chunk" of data, may be paint it then.

As HoverCraftFullOfEels suggested, you could paint this to a BufferedImage first and then paint that to the screen...

[SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) might be able to achieve this for you

**UPDATED**

This is the code I use to paint the above samples.

```
// Samples is a 2D int array (int[][]), where the first index is the channel, the second is the sample for that channel
if (samples != null) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    int length = samples[0].length;

    int width = getWidth() - 1;
    int height = getHeight() - 1;

    int oldX = 0;
    int oldY = height / 2;
    int frame = 0;

    // min, max is the min/max range of the samples, ie the highest and lowest samples
    int range = max + (min * -2);
    float scale = (float) height / (float) range;

    int minY = Math.round(((height / 2) + (min * scale)));
    int maxY = Math.round(((height / 2) + (max * scale)));

    LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(
            new Point2D.Float(0, minY),
            new Point2D.Float(0, maxY),
            new float[]{0f, 0.5f, 1f},
            new Color[]{Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.BLUE});
    g2d.setPaint(lgp);
    for (int sample : samples[0]) {

        if (sample % 64 == 0) {

            int x = Math.round(((float) frame / (float) length) * width);
            int y = Math.round((height / 2) + (sample * scale));

            g2d.drawLine(oldX, oldY, x, y);

            oldX = x;
            oldY = y;

        }

        frame++;

    }

}
```

I use an `AudioStream` stream to load a Wav file an produce the 2D samples.

Comment: Hello Mr. Mad Programmer i tried to paint it each every seconds but it freezes.i tried to paint also every 8th sample rather your suggestion four but no luck.

Comment: Painting every second probably isn't the best solution, given that it can more then a second to paint (my initial test was 2.18 seconds)

Comment: so , please give me the solution or it is best if you can give me any working example link , you r talking about.

Comment: even if comment repaint line  in the TimerDrawing class it still freezes the GUI and my whole application.

Comment: The I'd suggest that's not the problem area then.

Comment: hello Mr. wise Programmer can you post here the code from which you generated this output ?? so i can debug . i think now i am very near to my solution .

Comment: I don't know how useful it will be, but it's there

Comment: thanks Mr. wise programmer , after slight modification of your code and some hard work i have achieved what i want exactly. thanks again.

Comment: I'm thinking an `AffineTransform` would (also) be of use here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that your wave drawing code, which is being called from within a `paintComponent(...)` method is taking longer than you think and is tying up both Swing painting and the EDT.

If this were my code, I'd consider drawing my waves to BufferedImages *once*, making ImageIcons from these images and then simply swapping icons in my Swing Timer.

Comment: Hello Mr. Hovercraft Full Of Eels thanks for your advice i am trying it now and let you know.

Comment: Yes i know it Mr. Hovercraft , i wrote my first comment to Mr. Mad programmer.

Comment: Mr. HoverCraft can you give me a link of any working example you have suggested me in the comment.

Comment: @Mihir: nope I can't, but it shouldn't be hard to try to do.

Comment: I did the removal of comment , i posted it by mistake on your answer.

Comment: actually the byte i am getting is from TragetDataLine's buffer which is the numeric values of samples of recorded voice and i am trying to draw that bytes on the panel so i can construct a wave form in real time using those values.everything works fine but failed in painting on the panel.

Comment: Ah, perhaps what you want to do is to only draw that which is new, and leave the old graphics data unchanged. You could still use a BufferedImage for this I think.

Comment: even if comment repaint line  in the TimerDrawing class it still freezes the GUI and my whole application.

Comment: Then it's your other methods that are causing your problems as MadProgrammer suggests. Time to look into using a little background threading. 1+ to him.